# Python - Odometer Style Combinations of a 2D List

Tags: python, recursion, matrix

I have a N-by-N matrix containing only zeroes and ones, and each column must only have one '1' in it. The elements below the diagonal must be zero (A[1][1], A[2][1], A[2][2], A[3][1], A[3][2], A[3][3] = 0). For example:

```
A = [[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

I need to store all combinations of this matrix, that maintains the rules given before. My thinking for this is to have the first row start with all ones, and then move the '1' in the last column down one place at a time until it reaches the bottom. Then the second-to-last column '1' will move down one place and the last column '1' will repeat its cycle. This continues through all possible combinations.

Sorry if this is hard to understand, but it's similar to an odometer where when the rightmost dial does a full rotation, the second-to-rightmost dial turns one place. The only difference being that in an odometer, each dial has ten values, where as in this scenario the number of values varies (due to the values below the diagonal needing to be zero).

Because I don't know the size of the matrix I can't use a set number of nested for loops and I'm not sure how to implement this program recursively. I've also looked at `itertools.product` but I'm not sure how to use it to handle the diagonal rule with this. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "all combinations of the matrix"? How can a matrix be combined?

Comment: As in all variations of the matrix that still adhere to those rules. For instance: [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]] also matches these rules (one '1' per column and no '1's below the diagonal). So I need to store this matrix along with any other that adheres to the rules

Comment: From your explanation, by the given matrix, doesn't exist a matrix that will maintains the previous rules

Because for two rows, there are '1' for the same column (row 0 and row 3)

Comment: So you need to generate the rows? Or you need to start from a given matrix?

Comment: Ah true, I think I mixed up the rows and columns there. In any case, in one dimension (row or column) there can only be one '1' in that dimension. In the other dimension (column or row) there can be multiple '1's. I don't need to start from a given matrix, I just need to generate all matrices that adhere to the rules

Comment: And for example, can be your matrix filled with only zeros?

Comment: No, it must contain one '1' in each column

Comment: is the recursion mandatory?

Comment: No not at all, I was thinking that might be a good way to tackle it, but if you have a better approach that'd be perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attempt without the use of recursion, where N is your matrix width:

```
import itertools

def column(index, length, size):
    res = [0]* (length-1)
    res.insert(index,1)
    return res + [0]*(size - len(res))

N = 4

l = []
for i in range(1, N+1):
    l1 = []
    for j in range(0,i):
        l1.append(column(j,i,N))
    l.append(l1)

result = [list(x) for x in [zip(*r) for r in itertools.product(*l)]]
```

For each column it creates a list of every possible sequence of zeroes and one which respects the conditions. Then it combines them to obtain all the matrix listed by columns so it calculate the trasposed for each one of them to obtain the result. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. **However this is not a fast solution**. It uses a recursive implementations of the search function. At each recursion it explores all the possible product values for each row (excluding the first elements of the current row, until the diagonal value), and checks if the current solution is valid. If it reaches the recursion's end, it will append the current matrix solution.

hypothetically it explore n! solutions, but because I break the search when the solution is incorrect, the search stops before it reach all the possible solutions.

```
import sys, copy
from itertools import product


def recursiveSearch(actual, index, size, matrices):
    if index==size-1:
        for j in range(size):
            if sum([actual[i][j] for i in range(size)])>1:
                return
        if sum([actual[i][j] for i in range(size) for j in range(size)]) == size:
            matrices.append(actual)
            return
        return
    cur_row = len(actual)
    for j in range(size):
        if sum([actual[i][j] for i in range(cur_row)])>1:
            return
    pr = product([0, 1], repeat=size-index-1)
    for p in pr:
        new_row = [0 for k in range(index+1)] + list(p)
        new_matrix = copy.deepcopy(actual)
        new_matrix.append(new_row)
        recursiveSearch(new_matrix, index+1, size, matrices)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_ = int(sys.argv[1])
    pr = product([0,1], repeat=input_)
    matrices = []
    for p in pr:
        recursiveSearch([list(p)], 0, input_, matrices)
    for m in matrices:
        print(m)
```

A more efficient solution will be a search for column, and not for row which is how I'm doing the search now, because the check for correctness will require less computation (you need to check only if the current column sums exactly to 1)

And of course , the search for columns will need to shift the only 1 along the column